# Floyd-Steinberg error diffusion to grayscale levels not working properly for levels>=4

Tags: c#, image-processing

so I want to allow user to choose even number of grayscales for output image, 
I found pseudocode on wikipedia and implemented it ( I think properly), it works fine if I use 2 grayscales (black &white), but it reduces quality if I choose 4 and more grayscales instead of actually improving it.

[Orginal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy6p9.png)

[result after using 2 grayscales (black&white) which is good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr8q4.jpg)

will post 2 more pictures in comment (1.weird result after 4 grayscale dithering , 2. how proper result should look like with 4grayscales), because I dont have reputation to post more than 2 links...

here is my code:

```
public static byte Truncate(byte a, int b)
    {
        if (a + b < 0)
            return 0;
        else if (a + b > 255)
            return (byte)255;
        else
            return (byte)(a + b);
    }

public static Color FindNearestColor(Color color, Color[] palette)
    {
        int minDistanceSquared = 255 * 255 + 255 * 255 + 255 * 255 + 1;
        int bestIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < palette.Length; i++)
        {
            int Rdiff =(color.R) - (palette[i].R);
            int Gdiff =(color.G) - (palette[i].G);
            int Bdiff =(color.B) - (palette[i].B);
            int distanceSquared = Rdiff * Rdiff + Gdiff * Gdiff + Bdiff * Bdiff;
            if (distanceSquared < minDistanceSquared)
            {
                minDistanceSquared = distanceSquared;
                bestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return palette[bestIndex];
    }
```

here is my dithering function

```
public static Bitmap Dither(Bitmap image,int grayshades)
    {
        Color[] palette = new Color[grayshades];
        double start = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < palette.Length; i++)
        {
           double x = start;
            Color a =Color.FromArgb(255,(int)x, (int)x, (int)x);
            start += 255 / (grayshades - 1);
            palette[i] = a;
        }
        Color b = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
        palette[palette.Length - 1] = b;
        int height = image.Height;
        int width = image.Width;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width;x++)
            {
                Color currentPixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color bestColor = FindNearestColor(currentPixel, palette);
                image.SetPixel(x, y, bestColor);

                int errorR = (currentPixel.R) - (bestColor.R);
                int errorG = (currentPixel.G) - (bestColor.G);
                int errorB = (currentPixel.B) - (bestColor.B);
                if (x + 1 < width)
                {
                    image.SetPixel(x + 1, y + 0, Color.FromArgb(
                        Truncate(image.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 0).R, (errorR * 7) >> 4),
                        Truncate(image.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 0).G, (errorG * 7) >> 4),
                        Truncate(image.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 0).B, (errorB * 7) >> 4)
                    ));
                }
                if (y + 1 < height)
                {
                    if (x - 1 > 0)
                    {
                        image.SetPixel(x - 1, y + 1, Color.FromArgb(
                            Truncate(image.GetPixel(x - 1, y + 1).R, (errorR * 3) >> 4),
                            Truncate(image.GetPixel(x - 1, y + 1).G, (errorG * 3) >> 4),
                            Truncate(image.GetPixel(x - 1, y + 1).B, (errorB * 3) >> 4)
                        ));
                    }
                    image.SetPixel(x , y + 1, Color.FromArgb(
                        Truncate(image.GetPixel(x , y + 1).R, (errorR * 5) >> 4),
                        Truncate(image.GetPixel(x , y + 1).G, (errorG * 5) >> 4),
                        Truncate(image.GetPixel(x , y + 1).B, (errorB * 5) >> 4)
                    ));
                    if (x + 1 < width)
                    {
                        image.SetPixel(x + 1, y + 1, Color.FromArgb(
                            Truncate(image.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1).R, (errorR * 1) >> 4),
                            Truncate(image.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1).G, (errorG * 1) >> 4),
                            Truncate(image.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1).B, (errorB * 1) >> 4)
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

I have looked over this code many times and have no idea why it yields not nice result for grayscales >=4 , would be grateful if you could help me find the problem, also please pardon me if I broke any rule, its my first post here.
Thank you in advance for your help and kindness.

Comment: [weird result with 4 grayscales my program gives][3]                                                                                                       [how proper result with 4 grayscales should look like][4]                                                                                                                         [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/THR08.jpg
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xL4JQ.png

Comment: here is wikipedia pseudocode I am using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering